# Suggestions for Supplementation for weight loss

Tags: weight-loss

Does anyone have any suggestions for Herbal supplementation for weight loss that they have found to work for you personally?

Answer (score 4):

**STOP**
Do not search for any supplements to lose weight. Alter your diet and exercise. Taking supplements to lose weight is taking the easy way out, and it's **NOT** the solution for your problem. It will only cost you a lot of money and *won't work in the long term*. Most of the time these supplements are unhealthy because they contain a lot of caffeine or ephedrine. These herbal supplements cost a lot of money, and the only goal is to sell them on a short term. You will not lose weight over a long period.

**START**
Instead of looking for supplementation to lose weight, start looking for real food.
I'm a big fan of the Paleo approach. In this approch you lose weight by doing very little exercise (compared to conventional methods) and eating natural, real food. I would strongly advise you to give it a try. A lot of my clients lost tons of weight eating and exercising Paleo.

Take a look at [introductory Paleo video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uCFZoqmKf5M) on YouTube.

If you want more info about this approach please check out these websites and books:

- http://thepaleodiet.com/
- http://www.dietdoctor.com/
- http://www.marksdailyapple.com/
- http://robbwolf.com/2011/08/11/big-fat-blog-post-2/